# How to align text in different rows with defined margin

Tags: html, css

I am trying to solve one issue where I have table with 2 columns.(See the attached picture)

The problem for which I have not found solution yet is, that I need to have always 30px right margin from the longest text to right margin for second table column, but text in this column must be aligned to the left (the longest one and the others must start at the same position). Is it possible to achieve it?

[image]

Column with width set to 80% does not have to this width.

Comment: Have you tried using `padding-right: 30px` for the right column cells?

Comment: Yes of course. But the problem is that the unused space between the vertical red line on the picture and the right margin of the page stay.

Comment: Without seeing you HTML and CSS, trying to guess at a solution is not productive...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is to utilize the 'padding-' attribute.

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td style="padding-right:30px;">
            Test1
        </td>
        <td>
            Some other text
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="padding-right:30px;">
            Test185
        </td>
        <td>
            Some other text
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="padding-right:30px;">
            Test1
        </td>
        <td>
            Some other text
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Check it out here...  You can make changes and test it out.  http://jsfiddle.net/tfFbZ/

Comment: The problem is that i this component is like one colum of table and this table effect is created via divs.

Comment: You said in your first post, "I am trying to solve one issue where I have table with 2 columns."

However, if you must use divs, then use Twitter 'Bootstrap,' responsive grid.

Answer (score 0):

Add `padding-right: 30px;` for that table column

Answer (score 0):

Add `padding-right: 30px` to the second column. Simple as that.

Comment: See my comment above.

Comment: I can not provide original, but there is something similar http://jsfiddle.net/fht5c/. The problem is that the longest text in third colum should have padding-right set to 30px.

Comment: I think the floating `div`s without clearing floats is creating problems here. More on clearing floats [here](http://css-tricks.com/the-how-and-why-of-clearing-floats/)